# Adding daily data to existing file, based on list in file using awk

Tags: awk

I'm trying to add the daily totals from separate files to a single file. This is to count the number of daily transactions for different accounts. The accounts might not have a count on a specific day, so the account is not unique between the files. The data could be added to a single file and done in excel with a pivot table, but the number of accounts exceed the excel number of rows allowed.

File1_2022-03-01.dat

```
26159933386,12
26359222592,34
26459979727,56
26359925994,1
26461265992,22
26591926740,33
26465926740,44
```

File2_2022-03-02.dat

```
26159933386,3
26359222592,324
26459979727,43
26527939259,543
26461265992,32
26591926740,2
26465926740,443
26332060759,5
26465993472,33
```

Below the required output, Header would be optional, but nice to have. Every day's data should be added as a new column.
(At the end of the month, you will have daily data for each account, on which a total can be calculated, which can then be used to get the top users, and can be exported to excel.

Output_2022-03.dat

```
Account,2022-03-01, 2022-03-02
26159933386,12,3
26332060759,,5
26359222592,34,324
26359925994,1,
26459979727,56,43
26461265992,22,32
26465926740,44,443
26465993472,,33
26527939259,,543
26591926740,33,2
```

I have tried something like `awk -F, 'FNR==NR{var[$1]=$2;next;}{print $1","var[$1]FS$2}' File1_2022-03-01.dat File2_2022-03-02.dat` but not sure how to ensure that uniq account numbers from both files should appear in the output file. The same script should be used to add additional days.

Answer (score 0):

The problem simply cries out for SQLite.  You need one table with 4 columns: filename, date, account, and count.  Parse the date out of the filename, and produce a CSV or similar that can be loaded into a temporary table.  Use SQL to insert the rows from the temporary table to the main table, and delete the temporary rows.  Now you have your data.

SQL has "pivot tables" like Excel does, but (depending on the DBMS) can handle virtually limitless numbers of rows.  But it sounds like you don't need to pivot the values onto rows; it sounds like what you need is a sum by time-span and account.  SQLite and every other SQL implementation has date-time functions to operate on parts of dates, and GROUP BY to compute aggregates.

If for whatever reason your ultimate target has to be Excel, you can write the SQL to produce the data in whatever arrangement the Excel spreadsheet expects.  SQLite can export query results as a CSV file.

Could it be done just in awk?  Sure.  It could be done in C or APL, too.  I'm just telling you the easiest way, one that is far less error-prone than using a language that can't guard against data errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so fairly easily in `awk` by simple using an array indexed by the account number and then concatenate the second field as a string as the value. To provide sorted output, you can pipe to `sort` when done.

One solution in `awk` would be:

```sh
awk -F, '{acct[$1]=acct[$1]","$2} END {for (i in acct) {print i acct[i]}}' File1 File2
```

**Example Use/Output**

Using your data files, and piping to `sort` when done you would have:

```
$ awk -F, '{acct[$1]=acct[$1]","$2} END {for (i in acct) {print i acct[i]}}' File1_2022-03-01.dat File2_2022-03-02.dat | sort
26159933386,12,3
26332060759,5
26359222592,34,324
26359925994,1
26459979727,56,43
26461265992,22,32
26465926740,44,443
26465993472,33
26527939259,543
26591926740,33,2
```

(**note:** above the empty fields are excluded.)

**Handling Empty Fields**

To handle empty fields, you need to keep track of the number of files seen `nfiles` and then for each new file any new account not seen needs to have it's string prefixed with `","`. At the end, you also need to check the number of fields being output (using `split()` to indirectly check the number of `","` present in the string) and append `","` to any accounts that come up short, e.g.

```sh
awk -F, '
  FNR == 1 { nfiles++ }
  {
    if (FNR < NR) {
      $1 in acct || acct[$1] = acct[$1] ","
    }
    acct[$1] = acct[$1] "," $2
  }
  END {
    for (i in acct) {
      n = split(acct[i], tmp, ",")
      for (j = n - 1; j < nfiles; j++)
        acct[i] = acct[i] ","
      print i acct[i]
    }
  }
' File1_2022-03-01.dat File2_2022-03-02.dat | sort
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ awk -F, '
>   FNR == 1 { nfiles++ }
>   {
>     if (FNR < NR) {
>       $1 in acct || acct[$1] = acct[$1] ","
>     }
>     acct[$1] = acct[$1] "," $2
>   }
>   END {
>     for (i in acct) {
>       n = split(acct[i], tmp, ",")
>       for (j = n - 1; j < nfiles; j++)
>         acct[i] = acct[i] ","
>       print i acct[i]
>     }
>   }
> ' File1_2022-03-01.dat File2_2022-03-02.dat | sort
26159933386,12,3
26332060759,,5
26359222592,34,324
26359925994,1,
26459979727,56,43
26461265992,22,32
26465926740,44,443
26465993472,,33
26527939259,,543
26591926740,33,2
```

Let me know if you have further questions.